# Threading Decasteljau algorithm in golang

Tags: algorithm, go, concurrency, 3d, de-casteljau

I'm trying to write a threaded Decasteljau algorithm for control polygons with any set of points in golang but can't get the goroutines to work right because their work randomly and i can't manage to get all the goroutines to work .
here's my code for the `decasteljau.go` file :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type ControlPolygon struct {
    Vertices []Vertex
}

type Spline struct {
    Vertices map[int]Vertex
}
type splinePoint struct {
    index  int
    vertex Vertex
}

func (controlPolygon ControlPolygon) Decasteljau(levelOfDetail int) {

    //
    // LevelOfDetail is the number of points in the spline
    //

    spline := Spline{make(map[int]Vertex)}

    splinePointsChannel := make(chan splinePoint)

    for index := 1; index < levelOfDetail; index++ {
        splinePoint := splinePoint{}
        splinePoint.index = index
        pointPosition := float64(index) / float64(levelOfDetail)

        go func() {
            fmt.Println("goroutine number:", index)
            splinePoint.findSplinePoint(controlPolygon.Vertices, pointPosition)
            splinePointsChannel <- splinePoint
        }()

    }

    point := <-splinePointsChannel

    spline.Vertices[point.index] = point.vertex
    fmt.Println(spline)
}

func (point *splinePoint) findSplinePoint(vertices []Vertex, pointPosition float64) {

    var interpolationPoints []Vertex

    if len(vertices) == 1 {
        fmt.Println("vertices : ", vertices)
        point.vertex = vertices[0]
    }
    if len(vertices) > 1 {

        for i := 0; i < len(vertices)-1; i++ {
            interpolationPoint := vertices[i].GetInterpolationPoint(vertices[i+1], pointPosition)

            interpolationPoints = append(interpolationPoints, interpolationPoint)
        }

        point.findSplinePoint(interpolationPoints, pointPosition)

        fmt.Println()
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Done Detailing ..")
        return
    }
}

func main() {
    v1 := Vertex{0, 0, 0}
    v2 := Vertex{0, 0, 1}
    v3 := Vertex{0, 1, 1}
    v4 := Vertex{0, 1, 0}

    vectices := []Vertex{v1, v2, v3, v4}
    controlPolygon := ControlPolygon{vectices}

    controlPolygon.Decasteljau(10)

}
```

I'm also new to go concurrency and after a lot of research i'm still wondering if i need to use buffered or unbuffered channels for my case .
I also found that goroutines are mostly used for managing networks rather than optimizing 3D so i would love to know if i'm using a good stack for writing concurrent 3D algorithms